# Can I redirect a subdomain to an IP address with a port?

Tags: apache, dns, ip-address

I've got two addresses: `ipaddress` and `ipaddress:100`. The first one uses the default port of 80, but the second server (running GitLab) uses port 100. I have multiple IP addresses, but I am wondering if it is possible to have DNS link an address like `git.domain.com` to `ipaddress:100`?

Is this possible with DNS? I have full domain and root access, so any option is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNS only translates names into IP addresses and is oblivious to any port numbers.

However, you can use Apache as a reverse proxy to make the content accessible at `git.domain.com` by editing the virtual host file. I believe [this](https://serverfault.com/a/85115/191794) answer on Server Fault shows one method of how to do this that should work well for you.

Comment: In the answer you linked to would all the ports be changed to 80?

Comment: Only for the specific virtual host file you are editing. The ports would also not actually be *changed* to 80 they would just become accessible though Apache as the Apache service would be acting as a proxy/middleman.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a virtual server on git.domain.dom:80 that sends a 301/302 redirect to git.domain.dom:100